# Answer with link: Low quality or not?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Today in the Triage queue I received [this "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8463700) to look at. I already suspected this was an audit, so I paid extra attention and weighed all possibilities.

I like the answer, as it was quite thorough, but it lacked the example itself, only showing a link to the example.

As I understood, these answers are considered bad, as the link can point to a broken location in the future, so SO encourages to post the examples in the answers themselves.

Should I have voted this answer as "looks ok" or was there any other option in which I could have shown that I liked the answer, but that it was missing the actual example, and to show that the link might be broken in the future?

Comment: An answer doesn't always need code to be useful. From skimming, it looks like the author left a description of how to go about solving the issue. This is often even better than giving code. He added a link, sure, but there was much more to the answer. Looks ok to me

Comment: Since the rest of the answer was good content, the link is more of a courtesy.  As such, as long as the link is not spam, it's really irrelevant.  Even completely removing the link still results in an understandable approach.

Comment: ok, thanks. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Links are not *bad*.  We don't want to delete all answers that have links.  Rather, we want to ensure that all answers answer the question *without the reader needing to follow a link*.

This makes the review process actually quite easy.  Simply look at the question and *pretend that the link isn't in the question*.  If, after erasing the link in your mind, does the answer attempt to answer the question, or is the answer either empty or saying nothing meaningful?  If there's no answer left with the link gone, mark the post for deletion.  If there's an answer left there without the link, then it's still an answer *with* the link.

In this particular case, there's a great answer there even if there is no link, so there is no grounds for trying to delete the post.  This case is *exactly* how links should be used on SO; they should be there for additional information that compliments the self-contained answer that is provided.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! It is how I read an answer myself as well: first the text, and then follow the links for more information. I will judge those answers like that as well. Its a nice trick to first ignore the links, and then judge the answer.