# Moderator declined flag “Link-only answer”

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

Today I flagged the following two questions with a message saying they were `Link-only answers`:

[Support for script_file in Nest library for Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759564/support-for-script-file-in-nest-library-for-elasticsearch/30874916#30874916)

[Digital signature with iText and beID (using 2048 RSA key) on JDK8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060783/digital-signature-with-itext-and-beid-using-2048-rsa-key-on-jdk8/30885127#30885127)

But the flags was rejected with the following motivation:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

The above answers is clearly answers only containing a link, which as I understand it is discouraged as stated in:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

The above page states:

> Why and how are some answers deleted?
>
> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed.
>   This includes answers that are:
>
> commentary on the question or other answers
>   asking another, different
>   question
>   “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
>   exact duplicates of other
>   answers
>   barely more than a link to an external site
>   not even a partial
>   answer to the actual question

So I don't understand why my flags was rejected?

Comment: Did you use custom flags, or the "link-only answer" option?

Comment: The first one is definitely link only. The second is not. Maybe a poor answer but an answer nonetheless. His answer was to use a newer version.

Comment: @Cerbrus There is no "link-only answer" flag option.

Comment: `The above answers is clearly answers only containing a link, which as I understand it is discouraged as stated in:`  See [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297046/answer-with-link-low-quality-or-not/297047#297047).  That the answer contains a link doesn't mean it's a problem.

Comment: @Servy: Ow derp. In that case, it should've been flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that the first "answer" is link only and not an answer.  There's no meaningful text there.  This is further supported by [Patrick Hoffman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759564/support-for-script-file-in-nest-library-for-elasticsearch/30874916#comment49826943_30874916) saying that the extra link really should have been an edit (and he edited the original answer).  So as long as you used the standard Not an Answer (NAA) flag and **not a custom moderator flag**, you were correct and unlucky.

You didn't use a NAA flag though; per your admission, you used a custom flag that stated only "link-only answer". As [Shog points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297157/moderator-declined-flag-link-only-answer/297160?noredirect=1#comment208084_297160), mods are likely to err on the side of caution and only delete (mark helpful) flags where a problem is obvious in either the answer summary **or the flag text itself**.  This answer, while certainly not an answer, at *appears* initially to have other explanation beyond the link, and you didn't use the opportunity to explain the problem in your flag text. "Link-only answer" is a handy shorthand term for discussing these answers, but a poor description for a specific problem - if you'd written "this should've been an edit on the author's other answer", that would've been more likely to be seen as helpful... Especially if you'd done as Patrick did and made the edit before flagging.

The second flagged answer explicitly gives an answer:

> Answer is : use "future" version of the middleware :
>
> This issue should be fixed in the future release build (v410), [link here]

This may not be the best answer in the world, but it is an answer.  Your flag was correctly declined.

Don't worry too much about this; a couple of declined flags every now and then is not really a big deal. Learn from it and do better next time!

Comment: The first post should indeed be deleted, but it's still wrong to use a mod flag to indicate it.  So it was correct to decline that flag with the "does not require moderator attention" decline reason.

Comment: I said that that I should have been declined for that reason.  Whether it was or not we couldn't say.  It would have certainly been incorrect to mark it as helpful.

Comment: The "NAA" flag isn't correct in this case, either. The answer was low quality, but it was an answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus for the first one?  Stripping out the link, the text is not sufficient for an answer.  Well, at any the NAA flag I threw on it was marked helpful and I can't see the (now deleted) post anymore.

Comment: So, clearly the problem was an author who didn't realize he should edit his existing answer and instead posted an updates as a new post. A moderator would've likely been quick to handle this **if that's what the flag had said!** As usual, the problem with the declined flag wasn't [a lack of some magic incantation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers/183676#183676), but rather **the lack of any relevant information.**

Comment: @Shog9 quick question.  Do mods see the full "answer" and comments when handling NAA flags?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Not right away. We need to click on some expando controls to see the whole thing.

Comment: Not necessarily, @ryanyuyu. They *can*, but by default they just see an excerpt - if that isn't gushing blood and the flag doesn't state a problem, it's extremely likely it'll just be declined with no further investigation.

Comment: @Shog9 Ok thanks.  I'm going to further edit this answer to explain this.  I'd appreciate if you also made any further edits to ensure my understanding of mods handling NAA flags is correct.

Comment: @Shog9 updated the post.

Comment: Edited to clarify further, @ryanyuyu.

Answer (score 2):

You used a custom flag to flag a link-only answer.

Custom flags enter a queue to be validated by a moderator. For simple issues like this, there is really no need to get a moderator involved, and usually, flags like this get rejected (and are frowned upon). ***Only*** use custom flags for cases that absolutely require a mod to get involved.

Instead of the custom reason, flag the answer as "low quality". This will add the answer to the review queue, where users can actually flag a answer as being link-only.